# What should the permissions be on for PostgreSQL /data files?

Tags: permissions, mac-osx, unix, postgresql

I installed Postgres 9.3 from the osX binary.
When I attempted to restart using pg_ctl restart, I received the following error:

```
$ pg_ctl restart
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied

Bryan@bryans-mbp Fri Jun 13 13:41:24 ~   
$ sudo ls -la /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postmaster.pid  
Password:  
-rw-------  1 postgres  daemon  75 Jun 11 10:36 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postmaster.pid
```

Who should own this file and what should the permissions be?

Answer (score 5):

The permissions are correct as you want all of the data files and other associated stuff to be owned by the `postgres` user. I think the issue here is that the `postgres` daemon is not running as the `postgres` user.

To check which user the postgres daemon (postmaster) is running as, run:

Most *NIX (Like Solaris):

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

Linux

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

Make sure that as root, you are running:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data start
```

Adjust the necessary paths for `pg_ctl` and `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

You may able to just switch to os-level user to postgres user:

```
$ sudo su postgres
```

Then run the restart command:

```
$ pg_ctl restart
```